# Generics Fetch Firestore collection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, generics, swift5

I'm trying to create a generic function to fetch different collections and based on a given type let's say `T` convert all of the documents to `T` and then fill and return an array.

The problem is that at this line `let item: T = T.init(document: document)` I get an error saying `Type 'T' has no member 'init'` even without `.init` it fails.

Here is an example of a type that will be passed to this generic function.

```
struct Package: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let documentReference: DocumentReference

    init(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.documentReference = document.reference
}
```

Here is my code:

```
static func fetchCollection<T>(collection: String, completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void) {
    var array: [T] = []
    db.collection(collection).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
            guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            for document in snapshot.documents {
                let item: T = T.init(document: document)
                array.append(item)
            }
            completion(array)
        }
    }
}
```

Function call:

```
FirebaseViewModel.fetchCollection<Package>(collection: "packages") { packages in
    self.userData.packages = packages
}
```

Comment: As I see you don't use your struct anywhere right?

Comment: right. I was thinking of using it when I call the function as a `Package` type

Comment: Can you edit with the function call? I think you should `fetchCollection<T:Package>`. To declare T as Package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Generics on top method signatures cannot be constrained to struct, thus a protocol abstraction will be required.

**Create `PackageProtocol`**

```
protocol PackageProtocol {
    init(document: DocumentSnapshot)
}
```

**Conform `Package` to `PackageProtocol`**

`struct Package: PackageProtocol`

**Change your method signature to:**

`static func fetchCollection<T: PackageProtocol>(collection: String, completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void)`

## Original Answer

In your context **T** is not constrained to any type at all, thus it won't recognize your initializer.

I would change the method signature to:

`static func fetchCollection<T == Package >(collection: String, completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void)`

or if you expect different types of `Package`

`static func fetchCollection<T: Package >(collection: String, completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void)`

Comment: Now i get an error `Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Package'

Comment: Oh yeah sure, because of the struct, you will need a protocol! Please let me update my answer!

Comment: one small question. is it better to run the for loop in the method or better to do it in the protocol?

Comment: If you want to create a handy method to help you, I guess you can create an extension, but it's a matter of code style. However one change I would do, it would be to use high order functions (`map`, `flatMap` or `compactMap`), instead of creating a new array there.